# Global configuration of ngx-bootstrap datepicker format

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

Is it possible to globally configure a date format for the ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

The documentation mentions the BsDatepickerConfig class and how to pass it to each individual datepicker, but im a bit surprised that there seems to be no possibility to configure this globally (at least not documented)

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#bs-datepicker-config

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is not yet documented, but it can be achieved pretty easy. We have several demos of that for different components (tooltips, popovers, etc) and the code for datepicker will be almost the same. If you want to configure datepickers globally, replace basic `BsDatepickerConfig` with your one in `providers` section of your component or module.

```
export function getDatepickerConfig(): BsDatepickerConfig {
  return Object.assign(new BsDatepickerConfig(), {
    dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  });
}

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [{ provide: BsDatepickerConfig, useFactory: getDatepickerConfig }]
})
```

Example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvahsw?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Thanks, perfect!
Solved my problem

Comment: How to use it in a component?